How much memory does a process on Windows really use?
Platform characteristics:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8265U CPU @ 1.60GHz 1.80 GHz
8GB RAM
Windows 10  Visual Studio
MSVC compiler
I wrote the following code in C++ and then I run this executable with Microsoft .NET API (class System.Diagnostics.Process) and print statistics about the process through some time intervals.
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
   long long n = 1'000'000'000;
   std::cout << "part 1 started" << std::endl;
   char* arr = static_cast<char*>(malloc(n));
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
   arr[n - 1] = rand();
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
   std::cout << "part2 started" << std::endl;
   for (long long i = n / 5.0 * 4.0; i < n; i++)
      arr[i] = rand();
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
   std::cout << "part3 started" << std::endl;
   for (long long i = n/5; i < n; i++)
      arr[i] = rand();
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
   long long tmpll = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
   {
      tmpll = 0;
      if (rand() % 2)
         tmpll = 2'400'000'000;
      if (rand() % 2)
         tmpll += 2'400'000'000;
      if (rand() % 2)
         tmpll = 2'400'000'000;
      tmpll += rand();
      tmpll += rand();
      if (tmpll < 0) tmpll = abs(tmpll);
      tmpll %= n;
      arr[tmpll] = rand();
   }
   std::cout << arr[rand() % n] << std::endl;
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
   std::cout << "ended" << std::endl;
   free(arr);
   std::cout << "freed" << std::endl;
}

I printed PrivateMemorySize64, WorkingSet64, and PeakWorkingSet64 fields, and got the amount I asked to allocate in PrivateMemorySize64, but always a smaller value (usually no more than 80% of allocated space) in PeakWorkingSet64.
I read that Windows automatically loads rarely used pages on disk, so it is ok. But just now I've disabled swap file usage (now malloc fails for 2GB even while it worked correctly with swap file for 8GB on the system with 3GB free RAM, and the code worked correctly as well using 3GB PeakWorkingSet) and still got this result:
PrivateMemorySize64 = 1002602496
WorkingSet64 = 803287040
PeakWorkingSet64 = 803291136

How is that possible? I cannot really imagine an optimization that allows not to really store 1GB memory as I write into random places of the array for a long time. I thought even when I was not accessing the whole array and just printed a random element, it had to store all 1GB.
Please tell me what Windows 10 does really do here.
I reloaded the computer after disabling page file usage. Then I turned swap file usage back and got the same result:
PrivateMemorySize64 = 1002516480
WorkingSet64 = 803246080
PeakWorkingSet64 = 803299328


You need not have coded any of that.  The VS debugger can provide all those runtime stats directly, as can Task Manager.  Also it is largely an operating system memory management question.

Well, I am not sure what exactly is called VS debugger, but
can it start any executable file on my computer, attach to this process and print any memory usage statistics I want in the format I want (like through time intervals I want) without slowing down the app? I think it cannot and Task Manager cannot too. So it makes sense to write your own memory usage profiler (though "profiler" is not quite correct here as it does not modify the code, just request OS information about the process).

I do it on C# for now but I think it can be done with WinAPI on C. I did not figure out though how can I update the information about the process right at the moment it is terminated by OS. With this oppotrunity it will be possible to see memory usage of very short-time processes and get exact information, like exact PeakWorkingSet and WorkingSet at the end (e. g. if its big it can be a memory leak). I would be grateful if you give me a hint how to do in on C/C++/C#. And other things besides memory usage can be done with Intel profilers, but they aint got mem usage on Windows what is strange.

"VS Debugger" - the debugger in Visual Studio. You may have to explicitly open the appropriate stats window. Probably not just any process - that would be off topic here in any event.

I figured out how to do this, see https://github.com/ChessMastery/WindowsMemoryAnalyzer.

If you want to understand the numbers, read Mark Russinovich's book Windows Internals. Part 1 describes processes and memory management.
You need to distinguish between virtual memory, which is what your process has access to, and physical memory, which is the RAM of your PC.
Some of the virtual memory must also be in RAM, because the CPU needs to work with it. This is called working set. The rest of the virtual memory is either swapped to disk, or may even be non-existent yet (reserved only).
Memory can be allocated (committed or reserved) in a certain granularity (typically 64k) and swapped to disk in sizes of a page (typically 4k).
For your C++ code, it matters

whether you build a 32 bit or 64 bit executable,
whether you have a debug build or a release build,
whether you run it under a debugger,
whether you have enabled various memory handling flags (GFlags)

So, from the code only, it's not possible to tell how much memory it will use.
As for the 2 GB allocation of a single block, this may fail due to memory fragmentation. E.g. a 32 bit application may access 4 GB of virtual memory at may. Now consider a DLL being loaded at exactly the 2 GB boundary. This means that there's less than 2 GB below the DLL and less than 2 GB above the DLL. Thus, you cannot allocate a contiguous block of 2 GB.
Some notes on the code:

your code uses malloc() but does not #include <cstdlib>, so technically the code is not correct. Same for abs() and rand().

why use malloc() and free() in a C++ program, when we have new[] and delete[]?

if (tmpll < 0) tmpll = abs(tmpll); uses the C version of abs(), which takes an int parameter, but you use it with a long long variable. The behavior is implementation-defined.

abs(tmpll) returns an int, so you write only to 2 GB of memory when this is invoked. That's ok for the given 1 GB of memory, but may not be ok when you test with more memory.

tmpll += ...; may overflow and signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.


In order to fill a complete array, this code may be used:
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    constexpr auto SIZE = 3'000'000'000ull;
    auto arr = std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[SIZE]);

    // Find the page size
    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
    GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
    auto pageSize = sysInfo.dwPageSize;

    // Fill the array
    // Accessing one byte per page is enough
    for (auto i = 0ull; i < SIZE; i+=pageSize)
        arr[i] = static_cast<char>(rand());

    // Get Memory statistics
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
    GetProcessMemoryInfo(GetCurrentProcess(), &pmc, sizeof(pmc));
    std::cout << "Working Set Size: " << pmc.WorkingSetSize << '\n';
    std::cout << "Peak Working Set Size: " << pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize << '\n';
    std::cout << "Page File Usage: " << pmc.PagefileUsage << '\n';
    std::cout << "Peak Page File Usage: " << pmc.PeakPagefileUsage << '\n';
}

Output on my machine, compiled as C++20, 64 bit, release build, no debugger, page file disabled and rebooted:
Working Set Size: 3003518976
Peak Working Set Size: 3003523072
Page File Usage: 3008671744
Peak Page File Usage: 3008692224

Looks good to me. Everything is in physical RAM, so working set size is 3 GB. Interestingly, it also gives a page file usage of 3 GB, although that is set to 0 MB across all drives:


I am running a 64-bit executable in Release mode and I did not enable any flags in Visual studio (used default options). I wonder whether such flags can affect the PeakWorkingSet at the end of this code with disabled swap file? Could you please provide an example where a big array (500MB at least) is allocated by malloc and at the end PeakWorkingSet is almost equal to PrivateMemorySize? I will look through the book you adviced but there could be no answer for my question though.

My point is:

If I disable swap file, write the numbers to the whole array and then print a number at random index (or even repeat it N times), the whole array must be stored in RAM (where else?).
In this case the pages in which the array is stored are all mapped to physical memory pages (if it is not done this way, I wonder which way is it done then), so why PeakWorkingSet is not equal to PrivateMemorySize?


@vev01: "write numbers to the whole array" - that's not what the given code does. Also, the code uses signed integer overflow, which is technically UB, I believe. Also, abs() works for int only, not for long long. Not sure if that has an effect here. How did you disable swapping? Are you sure that you rebooted?

Lmao thats a double fail! First, I forgot to iterate through first 1/5 of the array when I initialized it. The second thing is I forgot rand() does not have to return an int from the whole int range, it appears to be restricted by 32000 + something in my case. So I never accessed first 1/5 of the array and got 0.8 GB. Then I fixed initialization and got 8,5 GB with swap file and 1GB with swap file disabled.
The reason I used malloc is it does not initialize the memory unlike new, so I wanted to watch how physical memory grows. Mkay, I am crowling away with an embarassed face.

@vev01: don't be embarrassed. It has happened to all of us.

The discrepancy between allocated memory (PrivateMemorySize64) and the working set (WorkingSet64) is due to Windows' memory management. When you allocate memory using malloc(), Windows reserves virtual memory, but physical memory (RAM) is only allocated when the memory is accessed. The working set represents the memory portion actively in use and kept in RAM, while less-used pages may be trimmed or not allocated until needed. This behavior is as expected and reflects the efficient optimization of memory, even while the page file is disabled.

That is what my question is about: I think I am surely using the whole allocated space for the array, as I first initialized it with rand() and then write rand() at rand()%n indices. I mentioned in the post that I turned off the swap file usage, so where does Windows store those pages that are not in working set? Maybe there is an optimization in the usage (and I am asking what can it be exactly), but working set seems like it does not change as I increase the number of iterations writing arr[rand() % n] = rand().
